# Call emacs function from terminal and obtain the same behaviour

Tags: spacemacs, functions

I have this simple function that opens an external shell (st) in the same directory of the current buffer:

```
(defun external-shell-in-dir ()
  (interactive)
  (start-process "st" nil "st"))
```

However, if I type in the terminal `emacsclient -e "(external-shell-in-dir)"` it opens a terminal in my home directory and not in the directory of the current window of emacs.

By the way, I am using spacemacs and I need this for a script to use inside i3wm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your shell command will be picking up on whatever the `default-directory` is for the current buffer, and `emacsclient` sets the server buffer as the current buffer by default.  The current buffer needn't be displayed in a window at all, so although there will still be a "selected window" for the frame, you will need to select that window explicitly (which will make its buffer the current buffer for the duration).

Try this:

```
emacsclient -e "(with-selected-window (selected-window) (external-shell-in-dir))"
```

Of course that may or may not have selected the *frame* you intended, so you might want to wrap `with-selected-frame` around that, assuming you have a reliable way to choose it.

You may find it helpful to test the likes of:

```
emacsclient -e "(current-buffer)"
emacsclient -e "(selected-window)"
emacsclient -e "(selected-frame)"
emacsclient -e "(frame-list)"
```

If it's feasible for your use-case, I think using `with-current-buffer` and an explicit buffer to act on would be a more robust approach.

Comment: `emacsclient -e "(current-buffer)"` gives me the `*server*` buffer, while with `(selected-window)` I obtain the desired behaviour, thanks.